# Error: conflicting types

Tags: c, xml

I am writing code in C for an assignment.

This is the relevant code:

```
 //operation: text(elem)
xml_list *text(xml_list *elem){
  if(isEmpty(elem)){
    return Nil();
  }
  return append(text1(head(elem)),text(tail(elem)));
}

//operation: text1(elem)
xml_list *text1(xml_list *elem){
  if(isText(elem)){
    return Cons(elem,Nil());
  }
  else{
    return text(childeren(elem));
  }
}
```

This gives me the error: `error: conflicting types for 'text1'
xml_list *text1(xml_list *elem){`

I can't figure out the source of the problem. I have been working on this for 8 hours straight now, and I am kind of losing my mind over this. Please some one help me

Comment: Have you tried googling what "conflicting types" means for your compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by the time it reaches

```
return append(text1(head(elem)),text(tail(elem)));
```

The compiler doesn't know the return type of `text1`. So it assumes `int` and remembers it. And later when it reaches the definition of text1 it will be conflicting.

To solve this forward declare text1 like

```
xml_list *text1(xml_list *); // <---- Here

xml_list *text(xml_list *elem){
  if(isEmpty(elem)){
    return Nil();
  }
  return append(text1(head(elem)),text(tail(elem)));
}

//operation: text1(elem)
xml_list *text1(xml_list *elem){
  if(isText(elem)){
    return Cons(elem,Nil());
  }
  else{
    return text(childeren(elem));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use `text1`

```
xml_list *text(xml_list *elem){
  if(isEmpty(elem)){
    return Nil();
  }
  return append(text1(head(elem)),text(tail(elem)));
}
```

before it is declared, so the compiler uses (unfortunately) the old "implicit `int`" rule, and assumes that `text1` returns an `int`.

When the definition that says it returns an `xml_list*` is encountered, that conflicts with the type obtained from the implicit `int` declaration.

Declare your functions in a header, and include that in the source, so that all prototypes are known when a function is used.

Comment: Can you write your own? If not, can you just declare the functions with a prototype (`xml_list * text1(xml_list *elem);`, ditto for `text`) at the top of the file? If not even that, what _can_ you do at all?