# warning: incompatible pointer types

Tags: c, xml

Following my previous [question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796223/error-conflicting-types)

Now I have this:

```
xml_list *text1(xml_list *);
xml_list *text(xml_list *);

//operation: text1(elem)
xml_list *text1(xml_list *elem){
  if(isText(elem)){
    return Cons(elem,Nil());
  }
  else{
    return text(childeren(elem));
  }
}

//operation: text(elem)
xml_list *text(xml_list *elem){
  if(isEmpty(elem)){
    return Nil();
  }
  return append(text1(head(elem)),text(tail(elem)));
}
```

when I run this I get this warning for xml_list *text1:

```
incompatible pointer types passing 'xml_list *' (aka 'struct xml_list_struct *') to parameter of type 'xml *' (aka 'struct xml_struct *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 if(isText(elem)){
```

also this warning for the next line:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'xml_list *' (aka 'struct xml_list_struct *') to parameter of type 'xml *' (aka 'struct xml_struct *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 return Cons(elem,Nil());
```

again another warning:

```
    warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'xml_list *' (aka 'struct xml_list_struct *') to parameter of type 'xml *' (aka 'struct xml_struct *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 return text(children(elem));
```

How can I make these warnings go away??

Comment: Well, what are the prototypes for `isEmpty()`, `Cons()`, and `children`()?  They're clearly incompatible with the arguments that you're passing.  You need to fix that.

Comment: isEmpty(xml_list *elems) and its return int. Cons(xml *hd, xml_list *tl) and it returns xml_list. children(xml *elem) and it returns xml_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory:

Your `isText`, `Cons` and `children` methods expect `xml*` (a pointer to an `xml_struct`). You are passing an `xml_list*` (a pointer to an `xml_list_struct`).

You make the warnings go away by passing a correct pointer (`xml*`)  or by fixing the methods to accept the pointer that you have (`xml_list*`)